# Discord Bump Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I've made this Discord Server, and I'm wondering how to make a Discord Bump bot! A bump bot is a bot where you do $bump it shows your ad msg in everyone's server that has the bot! This is useful for being able to advertising servers.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You aren't likely to get a good answer here without showing some effort

Comment: I've went to github and tried out some code, Nothing worked.

Comment: Could you show us the code you tried? The intention of this site isn't for someone to come by and write all your code for you. Many people here may not be familiar with the Discord API, or what exactly you mean by bumping a server. You have given us nothing to work off of.

Comment: Do you want to send the message to all channels? or just one? Some more detail would be appreciated.

Comment: This won't work as most bots block other bots running commands

Comment: @PotSkill All channels :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty vague but from what I can see, you need to send a message to (I am going to assume) the 'announcements' channel. To do this i recommend implementing something like this in your code.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def bump(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
            if channel.name == 'announcements':
                channel.send('Your Message')
```

You then of course need to also add you bot token and some basic discord.py setup to your script. But this should give you the basic idea of how to setup the bump part.